# Как подключиться к локальному серверу?

Tags: android, retrofit

Не получается подключиться к локальному серверу.
С эмулятора все проходит удачно, с телефона нет.
Использую `rx retrofit baseurl = адрес компьютера: порт 80`,Apache использует порт 80.

Подскажите,что нужно настроить?

Comment: Порт 80 случайно файрволом не закрыт?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: порт 80 закрыт wamp сервером